# how to retrieve a hierarchy of matches from a regex

Tags: regex, c++11

```
std::regex  r("((.)(.))(.)");
```

Running this on a three-letter string will simply return 5 matches. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49087e537c03c6eb).

Instead, I would like to retrieve two "toplevel" matches, where the first match contains two submatches. I would like to be able to nest them to any depth and retrieve a suitable tree of matches.

It appears as if boost has something like this with ["nested matches"](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/boost_xpressive/user_s_guide/grammars_and_nested_matches.html). Is this correct? And can I do this in c++11 without boost?

Extra: a slightly less trivial toy example where this might be useful:

```
((,[0-9]+)+)((,[a-z])+)
```

This would match a series of numbers, following by a series of words, all separated by commas. I would like to separate the number-matches from the word-matches, instead of having a flat series of matches.

Comment: What for? What do you believe you would be able to do with such a facility, that you cannot do without?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I've just added a slight more complex example to motivate this

Comment: You seem to believe you'd be getting a separate match for each repetition of the group. This ain't how `std::regex` works. You'd be getting exactly as many matches as there are opening parens in the regular expression, plus one. In other words, the number of matches returned is fixed by the syntax of the expression, and doesn't depend on the input being matched against.

Comment: I guess I just assumed that repetition (`*` or `+`) would lead to multiple matches. It seemed so obvious to me that I never tested it! Is there a way to do it? (I guess somebody has asked that already)

Comment: Have an expression that matches just one group, call `std::regex_search` repeatedly in a loop to find all matches.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about regex is that they are not recursive descent parsers. But you can use a combination of regex and C++ (or any other language, really).

Just a note, there are some problems with this regex:

```
((,[0-9]+)+)((,[a-z])+)
```

In order to not miss matching the first item, the list must start with `,`. The other problem is that you also will only catch lowercase 1 letter words.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to solve the first problem by assuming that you prefix each string with `,`. The second problem can be solved by changing the regex:

```
((,[0-9]+)+)((,[a-zA-Z]+)+)
```

<sub>Note that this will not capture more than one set of numbers followed by a set of words. For that you must search in a loop, as the comments said.</sub>

Now that that's fixed, I can explain how you might go about accomplishing what you want.

All of the numeric matches are in `matches[1]`. All of the alphabetic matches are in `matches[3]`.

You can get each individual item in the numeric list by splitting on `,`. The same goes for the alphabetic list.

Comment: In this case, will `matches[2]` be the same as `matches[1]`? And `matches[4]` the same as `matches[5]`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid No, `matches[2]` will only hold the last iteration that matched. Same for `matches[4]`. But there is no `matches[5]` (count the number of opening parenthesis).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `3` instead of `5`! Anyway, I understand now thanks. The fact that the last match is captured is potentially very useful - it would allow an automatic scheme to remove the individual matches repeatedly

Comment: I just edited my comment to swap 3 and 5. Good catch :-)